# OpenGL Exception thrown: read access violation, window was 0xCCCCCCCC

Tags: c, windows, exception, opengl

I am using the same framework which I had described in the previous question.

I solved it by creating a fresh dll instead of just changing the build type of the project from 'Windows Application (.exe)' to 'DLL (.dll)'.

But now when I use a variable of type GLFWwindow* in my structure and try to write or read. It always causes to pop up write access or read access violation respectively. The exception comes abruptly just as the window starts and then closes, showing the exception.

The exception says the following:-

**Exception thrown: read access violation.

window was 0xCCCCCCCC.**

It happens in the window.c file of GLFW and it points to the function which tries to read it. I even tried to use pointers to modify the window but still it didn't work.

Here is the code for the framework:- **Modified!**

**window.h**

```
#ifndef LIB_GRAPHICS
#define LIB_GRAPHICS

#ifdef LIB_EXPORTS
#define LIB_EXPORT _declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIB_EXPORT _declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#define LIB_FALSE 0
#define LIB_TRUE 1

#define LIB_BeginRender LIB_SetEvents(); LIB_ClearToColor
#define LIB_EndRender LIB_SwapWindowBuffers

#define LIB_CENTER_POSITION 0xCEAAFFEE

/* Define other things... */

typedef const char* LIB_String;
typedef unsigned LIB_Integer;
typedef char LIB_Char;
typedef int LIB_Bool;

/* Define the structures... */

typedef struct LIB_Window LIB_Window;

typedef struct LIB_Color
{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
    int a;
} LIB_Color;

/* Constructors, destructors and other functions... */

LIB_Bool LIB_EXPORT LIB_Initialize();
void LIB_EXPORT LIB_SetEvents();
void LIB_EXPORT LIB_ClearToColor(const LIB_Color color);
void LIB_EXPORT LIB_SetFrameColor(const LIB_Color color);


LIB_EXPORT LIB_Window* LIB_CreateWindow(const LIB_String title, const int x, const int y, const int width, const int height, const LIB_Bool resizable, const LIB_Bool fullscreen);
void LIB_EXPORT LIB_GetDisplaySize(int *width, int *height);

void LIB_EXPORT LIB_GetWindowFrameSize(LIB_Window* window, int *width, int *height);
void LIB_EXPORT LIB_GetWindowCursorPosition(LIB_Window* window, float *x, float *y);

void LIB_EXPORT LIB_GetWindowPosition(LIB_Window* window, int *x, int *y);
void LIB_EXPORT LIB_GetWindowSize(LIB_Window* window, int *width, int *height);
LIB_String LIB_EXPORT LIB_GetWindowTitle(LIB_Window* window);
LIB_Bool LIB_EXPORT LIB_IsWindowFullScreen(LIB_Window* window);
LIB_Bool LIB_EXPORT LIB_IsWindowOpened(LIB_Window* window);
void LIB_EXPORT LIB_SwapWindowBuffers(LIB_Window* window);

void LIB_EXPORT LIB_SetWindowPosition(LIB_Window* window, const int x, const int y);
void LIB_EXPORT LIB_SetWindowSize(LIB_Window* window, const int width, const int height);
void LIB_EXPORT LIB_SetWindowTitle(LIB_Window * window, const LIB_String title);
void LIB_EXPORT LIB_SetFullScreenState(LIB_Window * window, const LIB_Bool fullscreen);

void LIB_EXPORT LIB_DestroyWindow(LIB_Window* window);


void LIB_EXPORT LIB_Terminate();

#endif /* LIB_GRAPHICS */
```

**window.c**

```
#include "window.h"
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Create the structures... */
struct LIB_Window
{
    LIB_String title;
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    LIB_Bool fullscreen;
    GLFWwindow** window;
};

/* Start the functions here... */
LIB_Bool LIB_Initialize()
{
    return (LIB_Bool)glfwInit();
}

void LIB_SetEvents()
{
    glfwPollEvents();
}

void LIB_ClearToColor(const LIB_Color color)
{
    glClearColor((float)color.r / 255, (float)color.g / 255, (float)color.b / 255, (float)color.a / 255);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void LIB_SetFrameColor(const LIB_Color color)
{
    glClearColor((float)color.r / 255, (float)color.g / 255, (float)color.b / 255, (float)color.a / 255);
}

LIB_Window* LIB_CreateWindow(const LIB_String title, int x, int y, const int width, const int height, const LIB_Bool resizable, const LIB_Bool fullscreen)
{
    LIB_Window wind;
    wind.title = title;
    if (x == LIB_CENTER_POSITION)
    {
        const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        x = (mode->width - width) / 2;
    }
    wind.x = x;
    if (y == LIB_CENTER_POSITION)
    {
        const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        y = (mode->height - height) / 2;
    }
    wind.y = y;
    wind.width = width;
    wind.height = height;
    wind.fullscreen = fullscreen;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, resizable);

    wind.window = NULL;
    if (fullscreen == 1)
    {
        wind.window = (GLFWwindow**)glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL);
    }
    else if (fullscreen == 0)
    {
        wind.window = (GLFWwindow**)glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL, NULL);
    }

    glfwSetWindowPos((GLFWwindow*)wind.window, x, y);

    int screen_width, screen_height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize((GLFWwindow*)wind.window, &screen_width, &screen_height);

    if (wind.window == NULL)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return NULL;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent((GLFWwindow*)wind.window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    return &wind;
}

void LIB_GetWindowFrameSize(LIB_Window * window, int *width, int *height)
{
    int screenwidth, screenheight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(((GLFWwindow*)window->window), &screenwidth, &screenheight);
    *width = screenwidth;
    *height = screenheight;
}

void LIB_GetWindowCursorPosition(LIB_Window * window, float *x, float *y)
{
    double cx, cy;
    glfwGetCursorPos(((GLFWwindow*)window->window), &cx, &cy);
    *x = (float)cx;
    *y = (float)cy;
}

void LIB_GetDisplaySize(int *width, int *height)
{
    const struct GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    *width = mode->width;
    *height = mode->height;
}

void LIB_GetWindowPosition(LIB_Window * window, int *x, int *y)
{
    *x = (window)->x;
    *y = (window)->y;
}

void LIB_GetWindowSize(LIB_Window * window, int *width, int *height)
{
    *width = (window)->width;
    *height = (window)->height;
}

LIB_String LIB_GetWindowTitle(LIB_Window * window)
{
    return (window)->title;
}

LIB_Bool LIB_IsWindowFullScreen(LIB_Window * window)
{
    return (window)->fullscreen;
}

LIB_Bool LIB_IsWindowOpened(LIB_Window * window)
{
    return !glfwWindowShouldClose(((GLFWwindow*)window->window));
}

void LIB_SwapWindowBuffers(LIB_Window * window)
{
    glfwSwapBuffers(((GLFWwindow*)window->window));
}

void LIB_SetWindowPosition(LIB_Window * window, const int x, const int y)
{
    glfwSetWindowPos(((GLFWwindow*)window->window), x,y);
    (window)->x = x;
    (window)->y = y;
}

void LIB_SetWindowSize(LIB_Window * window, const int width, const int height)
{
    glfwSetWindowSize(((GLFWwindow*)window->window), width, height);
    (window)->width = width;
    (window)->height = height;
}

void LIB_SetWindowTitle(LIB_Window * window, const LIB_String title)
{
    glfwSetWindowTitle(((GLFWwindow*)window->window), title);
    (window)->title = title;
}

void LIB_SetFullScreenState(LIB_Window * window, const LIB_Bool fullscreen)
{
    const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    if (fullscreen == LIB_FALSE)
    {
        glfwSetWindowMonitor(((GLFWwindow*)window->window), NULL, (window)->x, (window)->y, (window)->width, (window)->height, 60);
    }
    else if (fullscreen == LIB_TRUE)
    {
        glfwSetWindowMonitor(((GLFWwindow*)window->window), glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), 0, 0, mode->width, mode->height, 60);
    }
    (window)->fullscreen = fullscreen;
}

void LIB_DestroyWindow(LIB_Window * window)
{
    (window)->window = NULL;
    (window)->title = NULL;
    (window)->x = 0;
    (window)->y = 0;
    (window)->width = 0;
    (window)->height = 0;
    free(window);
}

void LIB_Terminate()
{
    printf("BLITZ terminated by the user!!\n");
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Comment: Try calling `glfwGetFramebufferSize` after checking if `window == NULL`, not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `LIB_CreateWindow` returns a pointer to the loacal variable `LIB_Window wind;`. Once the function terminates, the variable goes out of scope and pointer points to "nowhere". This is an undefined behavior. Note, a local variable in a function is allocated on the stack, which is immediately freed, when the function is terminated.

You can fix this quickly, by declare the variable `static`:

```
static LIB_Window wind;
```

But, if you do so, then of course the library can only manage one window.

Either you create a dynamically allocated variable,

```
void LIB_CreateWindow( ..... )
{
    .....    

    LIB_Window *newWnd = malloc( sizeof(LIB_Window) );
    *newWnd = wind;
    return newWnd;
}
```

or you declare the variable of type `LIB_Window` outside the function and provide it to the function by pointer:

```
void LIB_CreateWindow( LIB_Window *ptr_wnd, ..... );

int main( void )
{
    .....

    LIB_Window wind;
    LIB_CreateWindow( &wnd, ..... );

    .....
}
```

Of course, the memory release of the `LIB_Window` data structure, in the function `LIB_DestroyWindow`, only works if the memory for the variable was dynamically allocated:

```
LIB_DestroyWindow()
{
    .....

    free(window); // <--- this only works if window was allocated by malloc 
}
```